# Not being able to do iCloud sync between devices

Tags: objective-c, ios7, synchronization, icloud

I have an app that uses core data and integrated iCloud. The app works fine for adding and deleting data with core data. But when it comes to iCloud only adding new objects is working. When I delete one object in one device, it does not get updated on the other one.

Here is my code for deleting in core data:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
Watchlist *stockToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[context deleteObject:stockToDelete];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error! %@", error);
}
}
}
```

And here is my code with the iCloud merge policy:

```
- (void)mergeChangesFromiCloud:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSDictionary *noteInfo = [notification userInfo];

[moc performBlock:^{
NSMutableDictionary *mergingPolicyResult = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[mergingPolicyResult setObject:noteInfo[NSInsertedObjectsKey]
                        forKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];
[mergingPolicyResult setObject:noteInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey]
                        forKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
[mergingPolicyResult setObject:[NSSet set] // Exclude deletions
                        forKey:NSOverwriteMergePolicy];

NSNotification *saveNotification =
[NSNotification notificationWithName:notification.name
                              object:self
                            userInfo:mergingPolicyResult];

[moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
[moc processPendingChanges]; 
}]; 
}
```

So, anyone could help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using a merge policy? Have you tried without using a merge policy?

Comment: As a matter of fact I used because it has on the book and since I was trying its example, it was on my project too. But for testing I commented out the method but the problem is still there, no sync after deleting an entry.

Comment: Ok, well it does work, are you updating the UI after the merge?  Take a look at this link to see more details on core data and iCloud integration.  Look at the way I post notifications to update the UI after receiving import notifications. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/

Comment: Well Duncan, the strange thing is that when I add a new entry it does sync normally, the issue is just when I delete.

Comment: Look in this code module for the storesDidImport method.http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/cloud-manager-methods/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using just this line

[moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

Not sure why you are modifying the notification.

Comment: It worked!!! I commented out the notification I had in mergeChangesFromiCloud: method and used your line of code. Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes not sure what you code was trying to achieve by modifying the original notification.

Comment: Me neither, as I said I was using the code from the book: "iCloud for Developers", page 351.